# How can I make the content of post-created objects appear with Intellisense?

Tags: typescript, types, intellisense

For example if i make a line like

```
let obj:{key1:any,key2:any} = {}
```

it will generate an `ts` error about missing properties.
If i use below method

```
let obj:{key1?:any,key2?:any} = {}
```

i can not be able to add new values to it else i make the `obj` as `:any` type and if i make it any i will not be able to see content on intellisense.

In a `nodejs` module I have used in the past, it's have the feature i mean

[image: prompts module example]

When I try to write similar code, I cannot provide the same feature

[image: my test]

how can i make it work with javascript or typescript?

Comment: You can do this with typescript, by giving `obj` a type. This is typescript 101 so if you are completely new to it, I would start by finding a tutorial. If not, perhaps you can share what you tried in typescript. Please share code, not screenshots of code.

Comment: i know some typescript, i can give a type to `obj` but i do not know what type i should give.

Comment: i tried few things but them not worked like i want and i think screenshoots more efficently for describe what i need

Comment: Screenshots are not better. Try to follow the rules of the board you are on to get the best possible help.

Comment: do you mean stackoverflow as board ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. People prefer syntax highlighted code so they can copy, modify and correct it in their answers. You're not going to get much help if you don't try. Also try giving obj a type while you are at it.

Comment: obj is a post defined value, and i do not know how to set expandable types

Comment: and my question is more about intellisense, and i cant describe it without screenshoots

Comment: intellisense uses types, so if you figure out how to give an object a type, you will get intellisense. So try your best there

Comment: for example if i write a line like `let obj:{key1:any,key2:any} = {}`, it will generate an ts error about missing properties, and lets think if its worked successfull i can not be able to add new values to it else i make it `:any` and if i make it `any` i will not be able to see content on intellisense

Comment: That last comment is a great basis for a stack overflow question. Please try to update your question with all that information + whatever exact errors you are getting. This is my last comment here because I feel i've repeated myself enough. Good luck